# Is the only way to add taxonomy terms via an admin panel?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

Is it possible to register taxonomy terms programmatically from a plugin? I would like to add a custom taxonomy 'geographical area' and also prepopulate the taxonomy with a list of areas in the UK.

```
public function sample_taxonomy() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'resellers',
        'wps-reseller',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Geographical Areas' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'area' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Also, how would I run this code only once as part of plugin activation? I am using the [Wordpress plugin boilerplate](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) activation functions.

Comment: Have you [already searched the site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=add+term)?

Comment: Apparently not thoroughly enough. apologies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`wp_insert_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term).

An example from the Codex:

```
$parent_term = term_exists( 'fruits', 'product' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
$parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id']; // get numeric term id
wp_insert_term(
  'Apple', // the term 
  'product', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'A yummy apple.',
    'slug' => 'apple',
    'parent'=> $parent_term_id
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is what I needed. If I add this on 'init' as per the codex, it is going to keep running on every request, though, isn't it? Can it be run just once somehow?

Comment: Yes, you don't want it running every page load but you will need to figure out when this needs to run. I can't tell you that. Plugin activation? When you save a post? Some other time?

Comment: I did try it in a plugin activation function but it didn't seem to run.

Comment: maybe because the custom post type doesn't exist on activation?

Comment: ___You have not posted enough code/context to give a proper solution for running this code only once___ (nor is that part of the original question), but you will probably want to hook a function on plugin activation that in turn hooks your "insert terms" function.

Comment: Thanks. Can you link to a reputable resource which describes how to hook a function on plugin activation?

Comment: How about this? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=plugin+activation

Comment: I should note that your question has been downvoted and voted to close for its lack of research effort (my guess) and that last question in the comments suffers from the same error. Please do some of your own research.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11171/discussion-between-codecowboy-and-s-ha-dum)